# retrofit.RetrofitError: Failed to invoke public javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty() with no args

Tags: javafx, properties, retrofit

I use retrofit 1.4.1 to receive json data from webserver with gson ，when the return type is normal java pojo it success,when the return type is contain JavaFX property it fail.

The interface in Server:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.z.beans.Department;

@Path ("/department")
public interface DepartmentService {
    @Path ("/query")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Department query(@QueryParam("name") String name);
}
```

2.the interface in JavaFClient:

```
import com.z.beans.Department;

import retrofit.http.Body;
import retrofit.http.POST;
import retrofit.http.Query;

public interface DepartmentService {
    @POST("/department/query")
    public Department query(@Query("name") String name);
}
```

3.the JavaFX Java pojo:

```
package com.z.beans;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
public class Department{
    private IntegerProperty id =  new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
    private StringProperty name =  new SimpleStringProperty("");

    public Department() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Integer getId(){
        return this.id.get();
    }
    public void setId(Integer id){
        this.id.set(id);
    }
    public IntegerProperty IdProperty() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name.get();
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name.set(name);
    }
    public StringProperty NameProperty() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

4.in the retrofit method:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(UIUtil.remotePath)
                .setErrorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler(window))
                .build();
        DepartmentService departmentService = restAdapter.create(DepartmentService.class);
        String name = "";
        name = null == name ? "" : name.trim();
        Department result = departmentService.query(name);//Failed to invoke public javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty() with no args
```